# python 3.5 for loop defined functions placed in the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Ok I have been trying to use a input Int function to set how many questions are asked at the start however the input doesn't seem to want to go through. It can be done right?  I all I want is to be be able to alter the  start_test() value. 
While when the user enter a inter correct answer I want the error message to display the correct answer after the Wrong.

```
import random
import string
import sys
# Used to refer to the what constinutes a vowel
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
# Used to refer to the what constinutes consonant
consonants = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase if x not in vowels]
#List of words used for 
candidateWords = ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'NAME', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'BIG', 'SMALL', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'PIGEON', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'SPY', 'RHYTHM', 'SUBSTANTIAL', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']
word_map = {x:{'consonants':len([y for y in x.lower() if y in consonants]), 'vowels':len([y for y in x.lower() if y in vowels]), 'letters':len(x)} for x in candidateWords}
ordinal_map = {1:'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd', 4:'th', 5:'th', 6:'th', 7:'th', 8:'th', 9:'th', 10:'th'}

def start_test(number_questions):
    current_question = 0
    correct_questions = 0
    if number_questions > len(candidateWords):
        number_questions = len(candidateWords)
    sample_questions = random.sample(candidateWords, number_questions)
    print(' Welcome to Samuel Mays English Test')
    print ('---------------------')
    for x in sample_questions:
        print ("Question {}/{}:".format(current_question+1,     number_questions))
        print ('---------------------')
        #
        current_question += 1
       #q_type or question type uses a random inter between one and 4 elif is then used to set up
       # what occurrs on an instance of each number in the set range
        q_type = random.randint(1, 4)
        if q_type == 1:
            # if one is rolled  the how many letter question is asked
             # it refers to the word map and looks at the letters entry.
            correct = word_map[x]['letters']
         #Input that is presented to the user
            ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(x))
        elif q_type == 2:
        # if two is rolled  the how many vowel question is asked
        # it refers to the word map.
            correct = word_map[x]['vowels']
        #Input that is presented to the user
            ans = input('How many vowels does "{}" contain?'.format(x))
        elif q_type == 3:
        # if three is rolled  the how many vowels question is asked
            correct = word_map[x]['consonants']
            ans = input('How many consonants does "{}" contain?'.format(x))
        else:
            n = random.randint(1, len(x))
            correct = x[n-1]
            if sys.version.startswith('3'):
                ans = str(input('What is the {}{} letter of "{}"?'.format(n, ordinal_map[int(n)], x)))
            else:
                ans = str(raw_input('What is the {}{} letter of "{}"?'.format(n, ordinal_map[int(n)], x)))
        if str(ans).lower() == str(correct).lower():
            print('Well done correct! :)')
            correct_questions += 1
        else:
            print('Wrong')

    print ('You have completed your test!')
    print ("    Score {}/{}:".format(correct_questions , number_questions))
    try_again = input('Would you like to try again? (y/n)').lower()
    if try_again == 'y' or try_again == 'yes':
        start_test(number_questions)

start_test(5)
```

tring to figure out how how to the results of a defined function into the loop

```
def prompt_vowel_count(word):
     correct = word_map[word]['vowels']
     ans = input('How many vowels does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
     return check(int(ans), correct)
```

Comment: Could you please post your error message?

Comment: What "loop below them"? The only loop I see is `for x in sample_questions:`.

Comment: I remember writing this for you, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. Which loop are you talking about? This one `for x in sample_questions:`? That doesn't seem to make any sense. I think you need to stop and think hard about what you are trying to ask and see if you can communicate it to us. Why do you have to change the code to get rid of the functions? Is it because your teacher told you to do that?

Comment: @jwpfox
You know how it generates a random number and then pulls a question associated with the number for example is gnerates a 1 it then creates a letter count  question I want to place what is occurring for example in  def question_letter_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['letters']
    ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(int(ans), correct                                                                      **Into the body of the loop**

Comment: @jwpfox You know how it generates a random number and then pulls a question associated with the number for example is gnerates a 1 it then creates a letter count question I want to place what is occurring for example in def question_letter_count(word): correct = word_map[word]['letters'] ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(word)) return check(int(ans), correct Into the body of the loop –

Comment: Again **what loop**. So what is stopping you moving the code that does the checks from where they are to where they need to be? If you understand what the code does that should be a fairly simple task. If you don't understand what the code does then it is very hard to help you.

Comment: @ TheLazyScripter 
The input part of for example def question_letter_count(word) is there a way to transfer what it does into the loop that contains for x in sample_questions:?

Comment: I would require a fairly large rework, may I ask the reason?

Comment: @ The boss/employer just say this number of functions is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
import string
import sys

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

consonants = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase if x not in vowels]

candidateWords = ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'NAME', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'BIG', 'SMALL', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'PIGEON', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'SPY', 'RHYTHM', 'SUBSTANTIAL', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']
word_map = {x:{'consonants':len([y for y in x.lower() if y in consonants]), 'vowels':len([y for y in x.lower() if y in vowels]), 'letters':len(x)} for x in candidateWords}
ordinal_map = {1:'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd', 4:'th', 5:'th', 6:'th', 7:'th', 8:'th', 9:'th', 10:'th'}

def prompt_vowel_count(word):
     correct = word_map[word]['vowels']
     ans = input('How many vowels does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
     return correct, ans

def start_test(number_questions):
    current_question = 0
    correct_questions = 0
    if number_questions > len(candidateWords):
        number_questions = len(candidateWords)
    sample_questions = random.sample(candidateWords, number_questions)
    print(' Welcome to Year One Greens English Test')
    print ('---------------------')
    for x in sample_questions:
        print ("Question {}/{}:".format(current_question+1,     number_questions))
        print ('---------------------')
        current_question += 1
       #q_type or question type uses a random inter between one and 4 elif is then used to set up
        q_type = random.randint(1, 4)
        if q_type == 1:
            correct = word_map[x]['letters']
            ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(x))
        elif q_type == 2:
            correct, ans = prompt_vowel_count(x)
        elif q_type == 3:
            correct = word_map[x]['consonants']
            ans = input('How many consonants does "{}" contain?'.format(x))
        else:
            n = random.randint(1, len(x))
            correct = x[n-1]
            if sys.version.startswith('3'):
                ans = str(input('What is the {}{} letter of "{}"?'.format(n, ordinal_map[int(n)], x)))
            else:
                ans = str(raw_input('What is the {}{} letter of "{}"?'.format(n, ordinal_map[int(n)], x)))
        if str(ans).lower() == str(correct).lower():
            print('Well done correct! :)')
            correct_questions += 1
        else:
            print('Wrong')

    print ('You have completed your test!')
    print ("    Score {}/{}:".format(correct_questions , number_questions))
    try_again = input('Would you like to try again? (y/n)').lower()
    if try_again == 'y' or try_again == 'yes':
        start_test(number_questions)

start_test(5)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're really helping the OP by continually writing their code for them.

Comment: @The LazyScript                                    thanks mate I but I already had that  I'll repaste what I have on to the desktop  on to the top panel.  According to the guy I'm making this for I need to only have one defined function. 
def question_letter_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['letters']
    ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(int(ans), correct)                                                             
I need to transfer it to the loop that set ups up the test

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I do not agree, you have posted an str cast on an evaluated input when there is already a raw_input function that returns that string without having to cast anything.

So this is a very poor answer and it does not help the OP
Edit: I did not see the version of python. My apologies about the raw_input information.

Comment: @Almasyx The OP has clearly defined the problem using 3.5. Therefore `raw_input` has been replaced by `input` and `input` has been removed. I type cast as a string to remind the programmer that the desired input was of type string.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to rewrite the program using only one function.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Yes, i didn't see the python version. I apologize.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter
The answer function seems to give correct and incorrect at the same time

Comment: @danielwong What do you mean?

Comment: I had to change a few bits to get to work but. Wait  a tick let me show you in the above panel. For example for "How many vowels are in potatoe I enter the correct amount and only wrong is displayed as a response. Basically the answers will only process as incorrect

Comment: Also @TheLazyScripter why is  'code'                                                   print correct
        if ans == correct:
            print('Well done correct! :)')
            correct_questions += 1
        else:
            print('Wrong :(')'

Why isn't there a parenthesis for it on yours?

Comment: Sorry, I use 2.7 and i tend to forget my '()' around print statements. I meant to remove that statement entirely because it was used for debugging. I am unsure how the above code gives you both correct and incorrect results?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter
No wait  it now only gives incorrect results even if the answer is correct. For example it asks how many letters are in cattle and I put down 6 and it still comes up as incorrect.

Comment: Ok I see. After fully testing, removing the pointless print and adding a version check for python 2.7 users I cannot seem to replicate you're results. I have however removed any chance for capitalization issues. Try the above code

Comment: Yea, and it's pretty easy

Comment: @TheLazyScripter hey sorry to bother you is it possible to use a input Int function to set the number of questions that are asked. That's what I have attempting but of course error after error.

Comment: Oh I was doing something completely different to try and call the information.

Comment: @ The Lazy Scripterif I want the vowel calculation to be a second defined fuction
Is there a way to call the results of the function into the loop?

Comment: @danielwong What do you mean by vowel calc

Comment: @The Lazy Scripter see above mate

Comment: @danielwong Revised my answer

Comment: thankyou so much and no I now what I was doing wrong when I was try to get the version on my desktop to do it

Comment: Could be an issue with declaration timing. It can be tricky when you're first starting out. basically if a function is declared and calls on a function that is lower on the page, declared later, then it will give an error stating that the function has not been declared